# Convert HTML document to PDF with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf, pdfmake

I have an Angular 11 application and I want to download a PDF from a given HTML. this HTML is not a component from my Angular app, is a HTML document independent from the application, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' xmlns='ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
        <style> p { color: red; } </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hi there</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to load this HTML and save as a PDF as it is. I tried using pdfmake to create the PDF but it ignores the style on the head tag.

```
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake'
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
import htmlToPdfmake from 'html-to-pdfmake';

export class MyComponent {
    myHtml: string = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en' 
xmlns='ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><style> p { color: red; } 
</style></head><body><p>hi there</p></body></html>";

    constructor() {
        let html = htmlToPdfmake(this.myHtml);
        let documentDefinition = { content: html };
        pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).open();
    }

}
```

PDF generated: [image]

the text should be red, why is it not red?

Comment: try inline styles

Comment: hi @AsmaaRashad, thank you for your response. I tried adding the style to the p tag itself like: `<p style="color: red">` . It does work, but the actual html document that I want to download as PDF is more complex, and has many more CSS definitions on HTML header.

Comment: you can read more about styling pdfmake from here 
https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/styling/

Comment: And before you ask the next question ... think about CSS applied from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can add inline styles like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' xmlns='ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="color: red;">hi there</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Asmaa, that does work, but as I answered in the comments, the actual html document that I want to download as PDF is more complex, and has many more CSS definitions on HTML header.